# Divs are overlapping horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create rows with divs, but they're overlapping. I'd like to have three rows, the second divided into two columns. The first row is great, but the second and third rows are overlapping horizontally.

```css
            .row {
                background: pink;
                padding: 20px 0;
            }
            .row-2 {
                width:75%;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .what, .why {
                margin: 0;
                width: 50%;
                float: left;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .row-3 {
                width: 100%;
                background: whitesmoke;
            }
            h3 {
                text-align: center;
            }
```

```html
<div class="row">
     <h3>Testing to see where this goes.</h3>
</div>

<div class="row-2">

    <div class="what">Chocolate cake liquorice cookie halvah apple pie fruitcake. Pudding apple pie cookie danish apple pie cotton candy candy jelly. Cookie soufflé muffin candy tiramisu caramels chocolate cake.
    </div>
    
    <div class="why">Chocolate bar chupa chups cheesecake soufflé croissant croissant marshmallow. Cookie soufflé muffin candy tiramisu.
    </div>
    
</div>

<div class="row-3">
     <h3>Testing to see where this goes.</h3>
</div>
```

It's totally basic, but I couldn't find an answer and it's been driving me crazy.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add float:left to ".row-3" in your CSS it will be positioned at the bottom.

Also add "box-sizing:border-box;" to ".what, .why" classes. This will allow padding without adding to the width of the divs so that they remain only 50% of their parent div in width.

Answer (score 0):

here man:http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/zrfpbvkq/1/

```
.row:nth-of-type(1) {
    width:100%;
    background:pink;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
}
.row:nth-of-type(2) {
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
}
.row:nth-of-type(2) div {
    padding:10px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:nth-of-type(3) {
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a common issue with floating elements. Second row needs a clearfix, such as `overflow: hidden;` to restore it's height and prevent the last row from overlapping it. I applied clearfix for all three rows and here's the working example https://jsfiddle.net/dore4sr8/.

css:

```
.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row-1 {
    background: pink;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.row-2 {
    width:75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.row-3 {
    width: 100%;
    background: whitesmoke;
}
.what, .why {
    margin: 0;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}

h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
```